# SWRevealViewController UIButton does not work after using another UIButton

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uikit, swrevealviewcontroller

It may sound confusing, but just bear with me.

I have 2 buttons in my ViewController.swift. One that reveals a side menu (this uses the SWRevealViewController), and another one revealing another ViewController.

Once I run the app, it lets me use the slide menu button no problem. However, if I use the other button to reveal another ViewController, THEN come back to the original ViewController (the one with the slide-out menu button), the slide-out-menu button does not work, rather it just blinks and does no action.

I tried programming it and looking at examples, however I have no luck.

Here is my viewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var BTN4: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var BTN3: UIButton!//This is the button that brings you to the other viewController
    @IBOutlet var BTN2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var BTN1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var Button: UIButton! //This is the SWRevealViewController being called
    @IBOutlet var Bar: UINavigationItem!

    var varView = Int()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 50 / 255.0, green: 132 / 255.0, blue: 255 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        BTN1.alpha = 1.0
        BTN4.alpha = 0
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func Clicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: ({
            self.BTN2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -90)
            self.BTN3.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -180)
            self.BTN4.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)
            self.BTN1.alpha = 0
            self.BTN4.alpha = 1.0
        }))
    }

    @IBAction func ClickedAgain(sender: AnyObject) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: ({
            self.BTN2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)
            self.BTN3.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)
            self.BTN4.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)
            self.BTN1.alpha = 1.0
            self.BTN4.alpha = 0
        }))
    }

    @IBAction func ButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        Button.addTarget(self.revealViewController(), action:#selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)), forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)//This is the SWRevealViewController Action
    }
}
```

Any help on this? I know it is a lot, but any type of help would be fantastic.